# Ajax Llenar campos input a partir de combobox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, combobox, autocompletar

necesito ayuda porque no puedo logar esto:
Aquí tengo un código que conseguí en la web y adapté para llenar combobox dependientes. Pero necesito que a partir de la selección del combo #sucursales se complete el campo input #Direccion, obteniendo datos de una tabla de la DDBB.
En el archivo "actioncombos.php" incluí la query $resultDireccion en la function getInternos donde intento obtener los datos que quiero imprimir en un input, pero el resultado es nulo.
Agradezco ayuda.
Dejo mi código:

solicitudes.php

```
<div class="form-title">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Cliente" id="BusClienteAbre"><a href="#">Cliente</a></label>
        <?php
        include("includes/conexion.php");
        $c=mysql_query("select id_cliente, razonsocial from clientes order by id_cliente ASC");
        ?>
        <select name="clientes" class="form-control" id="clientes">
            <option value="">-Seleccione Cliente-</option>
            <?php while($r= mysql_fetch_object($c)){
                echo "<option value=".$r->id_cliente.">".$r->id_cliente." - ".$r->razonsocial."</option>";
            } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>              
<div class="row mb40">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-title">
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <label for="Sucursal">Sucursal</label> 
                <input type="text" name="NoSucursal" class="form-control" id="NoSucursal" size="7" maxlength="5" placeholder="C&oacute;d. Sucursal"> 
                <select name="sucursales" class="form-control" id="sucursales" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="">-Sucursal-</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <label for="Interno">Interno</label> 
                <input type="text" name="NoInterno" class="form-control" id="NoInterno" size="7" maxlength="5" placeholder="C&oacute;d. Interno"> 
                <select name="internos" class="form-control" id="internos" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="">-Interno-</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <label for="Direccion">Direccion</label> 
                <input type="text" name="Direccion" class="form-control" id="Direccion" size="20"> 
            </div>
```

procesarcombos.js

```
$(function() {
    $("#sucursales,#internos").attr('disabled', true);

    function ejecutar(obj1, obj2, task) {
        $('<img />', {
            'class': 'loading',
            src: 'images/ajax-loader.gif',
            'style': 'display:inline'
        }).insertAfter(obj1);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "actioncombos.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: "task=" + task + "&id=" + $(obj1).val(),
            success: function(msg) {
                $(obj1).next('img').remove();
                $(obj2).html(msg).attr("disabled", false);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $(obj1).next('img').remove();
                alert("Error al ejecutar => " + textStatus + " – " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }


    $("#clientes").change(function(e) {
        $("#internos,#sucursales,#Direccion").attr('disabled', true);
        if ($(this).val().trim() != "") {
            ejecutar($(this), $("#sucursales"), "getSucursales");
        }
    });
    $("#sucursales").change(function(e) {
        $("#internos").attr('disabled', true);
        if ($(this).val().trim() != "") {
            ejecutar($(this), $("#internos"), "getInternos");
        }
    });

});
```

actioncombos.php

```
<?php
include("includes/conexion.php");
function getSucursales() {
    $cliente = $_POST["id"];
    $resultSucursales = mysql_query("SELECT id_clienteSuc, id_sucursal, descripcion
     FROM sucursales 
     WHERE id_clienteSuc = '$cliente'
     ORDER BY id_sucursal ASC  
     "); 
    echo '<option value="0">-Seleccione sucursal-</option>'; 
    if ($rowSucursales = mysql_fetch_array($resultSucursales)){ 
        do { 
            echo '<option value="'.$rowSucursales["id_sucursal"].'">';
            echo ''.$rowSucursales["descripcion"].'</option>';
        }
        while ($rowSucursales = mysql_fetch_array($resultSucursales)); 
    } else { 
        echo '<option>Cliente sin Sucursales.</option>'; 
    }
}
function getInternos() {
    $sucursal = $_POST["id"];
    $resultInternos = mysql_query("SELECT id_intaut, id_cliente, id_sucursal, apellido, nombres
     FROM internosautorizados 
     WHERE id_sucursal = '$sucursal'
     ORDER BY id_intaut ASC  
     "); 
    echo '<option value="0">-Seleccione interno-</option>'; 
    if ($rowInterno = mysql_fetch_array($resultInternos)){ 
        do { 
            echo '<option value="'.$rowInterno["id_intaut"].'">';
            echo ''.$rowInterno["apellido"].', '.$rowInterno["nombres"].'</option>';
        }
        while ($rowInterno = mysql_fetch_array($resultInternos)); 
    } else { 
        echo '<option>Cliente sin Internos.</option>'; 
    }
    $resultDireccion = mysql_query("SELECT id_sucursal, id_clienteSuc, direccion, nro, piso, depto, localidad, provincia, telefono
     FROM sucursales 
     WHERE id_sucursal = '$sucursal'
     ORDER BY id_sucursal ASC  
     "); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultDireccion)){
        echo '<input type="text" name="Direccion" class="form-control" id="Direccion" size="30" value="'.$row["direccion"].'" disabled> ';  
    }
}
if ($_POST) {
    switch ($_POST["task"]) {
        case "getSucursales":
        getSucursales();
        break;
        case "getInternos":
        getInternos();
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Comment: "Estuve investigando pero no puedo conseguirlo" no nos dice exactamente qué estás obteniendo ahora, si sale algún mensaje de error ni qué esperas obtener exactamente.

Comment: Ok, especificaré más:
Por ejemplo, hice una query de los datos que necesito en la function "getInternos" donde el id_sucursal = $sucursal y no logro obtener los datos ni hacer que se impriman en un input.
$resultDireccion = mysql_query("SELECT id_sucursal, id_clienteSuc, direccion, nro, piso, depto, localidad, provincia, telefono
        FROM sucursales 
        WHERE id_sucursal = '$sucursal'
        "); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultDireccion)){
echo '<input type="text" name="Direccion" id="Direccion" value="'.$row["direccion"].'"> '; 
}

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega la información que creas pertinente. No la pongas como comentario porque muchas personas no los ven.

Comment: Hola, pointup. Por favor especifica tu duda y en vez de poner cosas como "segundo combo" expecifica el nombre de este (o su id) o a qué hace referencia También describe el problema que tienes o cuál es el resultado que esperas.

Comment: Ahí edité un poco más la pregunta. Espero que esté mejor. Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿PHP recibe bien lo que envías por AJAX? ¿La consulta SQL trae resultados?

Comment: Aparentemente si, porque el combo #Interno lo llena bien.

Comment: si imprimes el msg que te devuelve el success te imprime "null"?

Comment: En este caso no devuelve ningun valor y el combo #Internos no se completa. Queda en blanco.

Answer (score 1):

Como estas usando AJAX:

1. cuando `#sucursales` cambia, obtener el `val` de la selección.

   ```js
   $('#sucursales').on('change',function(){
     var direccion; //guardara la direccion obtenida
     var sucursal = $(this).val(); //obtiene la sucursal seleccioanada
   })
   ```
2. hacer la petición AJAX asincrónica, pasar el `val` seleccionado y obtener resultados.

   ```js
   $('#sucursales').on('change', function() {
     var direccion; //guardara la direccion obtenida
     var sucursal = $(this).val(); //obtiene la sucursal seleccioanada

     //petición ajax
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "actioncombos.php",
       dataType: "html",
       data: sucursal,
       async : false, //espera la respuesta antes de continuar
       success: function(respuesta) {
         direccion =  respuesta; //repuesta
       },
     });
   })
   ```
3. vaciar el input  `#Direccion`.

   ```js
   $('#sucursales').on('change', function() {
     var direccion; //guardara la direccion obtenida
     var sucursal = $(this).val(); //obtiene la sucursal seleccioanada

     //petición ajax
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "actioncombos.php",
       dataType: "html",
       data: sucursal,
       async : false, //espera la respuesta antes de continuar
       success: function(respuesta) {
         direccion =  respuesta; //repuesta
       },
     });

     //limpia el input
     $('#direccion').val('');
   })
   ```
4. agregar nuevo resultado a `#Direccion`.

   ```js
   $('#sucursales').on('change', function() {
           var direccion; //guardara la direccion obtenida
     var sucursal = $(this).val(); //obtiene la sucursal seleccioanada

     //petición ajax
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "actioncombos.php",
       dataType: "html",
       data: sucursal,
       async : false, //espera la respuesta antes de continuar
       success: function(respuesta) {
         direccion =  respuesta; //repuesta
       },
     });

     //limpia el input
     $('#direccion').val('');
     //agrega la direccion
     $('#direccion').val(direccion);
   })
   ```

Comment: Respuesta Editada*

Answer (score 0):

lo que podría hacer es detectar un cambio en sus listas(combobox) con jQuery de la siguiente manera:

```
$(documet).ready(function(){
    $("#id_de_tu_lista").on("change", function(){
        $("#id_de_tu_input").val(valor); //aqui le asignamos un valor el cual usted define
    });
});
```

con esto detecta cuando se escoge una opción en le da un valor al input.

Comment: El OP ya hace eso. En los change de sus combos hace una petición AJAX. Su problema está en lo que devuelve o no dicha petición.